# Como usar areas apenas utilizando o root controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Criei um projeto ASP.NET MVC 5 onde eu tinha feito um *template*, então agora vamos ter vários *templates* divididos por *areas*. Só que os *controllers* vão ser os mesmos, Então eu não queria criar os mesmos *controllers* para todas as *areas*. Como eu faço isso?

```
 //exemplo link html 
     <a href='/home/index'> Home </a>

//controller:
    public ActionResult Index(){
        //aqui faço a verificação que retornará a area

        string retorno = obterAreaUtilizada(); //ex.:"template02"

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home", new { area = retorno });
    }
```

Só que eu estou testando aqui e está dando erro, por justamente nao usar *controller* nas areas... alguém poderia me ajudar?

EDIT

Achei uma forma, mas preciso saber se ela é coerente, e não uma gambiarra:

```
    public ActionResult Index(){
        //aqui faço a verificação que retornará a area

        string retorno = obterAreaUtilizada(); //ex.:"template02"

        string caminho = string.format("~/areas/{0}/views/home/index.cshtml",retorno);
        return View(caminho);
    }
```

Por favor, se alguém souber uma solução mais adequada, seria ótimo se compartilhasse. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Achei uma forma, mas preciso saber se ela é coerente, e não uma gambiarra.

É uma gambiarra. Você está na verdade fazendo o *Controller* ter que interpretar a rota obtendo a área pedida por requisição, o que é errado. O papel do *Controller* não é interpretar rotas, e sim processar uma requisição feita para uma determinada rota.

A maneira correta de fazer isso é registrando seu *Controller* num *namespace* comum a todas as rotas. Por exemplo:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Controllers.AreasComum
{
    public class MeuControllerDeArea : Controller { ... }
}
```

Na criação de uma área, será criado um arquivo chamado `NomeDaAreaAreaRegistration.cs` que registra uma rota para aquela área. Basta completar a parametrização da rota deste arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Areas.MinhaArea
{
    public class MinhaAreaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "MinhaArea";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "MinhaArea_default",
                url: "MinhaArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MeuControllerDeArea", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MeuProjeto.Controllers.AreasComum" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Escreva seus *Controllers* normalmente, apenas criando os respectivos arquivos de *Views* nos diretórios esperados de cada *Controller* dentro do diretório `Views` de cada uma das suas *Areas*.

Crie quantas *Areas* julgar necessário, repetindo o processo de registro de rota para cada *Area*.

**Atenção:** Se houver dois *Controllers* com o mesmo nome em *namespaces* diferentes, o controle de rotas pode se perder. Se isto ocorrer, é necessário explicar ao ASP.NET MVC qual o *namespace* padrão para busca de *Controllers*, da seguinte forma:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        // Insira a linha abaixo com o namespace padrão dos seu Controllers que não pertencem a Areas
        ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("MeuProjeto.Controllers");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Cigano, tenho uma duvida, como ficaria a url desta maneira? por que a ideia é fazer tipo www.algumacoisa.com/home/index e atraves do controller eu redirecionar para minha view. se eu fizer o que vc disse entrando nessa url como ficaria o retorno do controller?

Comment: ou usaria o primeiro bloco de codigo com redirectToView?

Comment: `www.algumacoisa.com/home/index` não entra em área alguma. Entrar em área seria algo como `www.algumacoisa.com/area/home/index`. O retorno é quase o mesmo dos *Controllers* normais da aplicação, mas num contexto isolado desses *Controllers* normais.

Comment: Então da maneira que você explicou eu teria que usar a .../minhaArea/... para acessar ela?

Comment: Exatamente. É para isso que as áreas existem.

Comment: o redirectToAction seria uma boa opção para fazer o uso de areas sem deixar explicito isso na url? como eu disse é uma mudança visual onde as areas são apenas views e js delas, algumas até como atalho por serem as mesmas views.

Comment: Áreas não são recursos para mudança de *templates*. `RedirectToAction` é uma função usada tanto por *Controllers* de Áreas quanto *Controllers* raiz. Você está tentando usar Áreas de uma forma errada. Sugiro fazer outra pergunta sendo mais específico que o que você quer é uma mudança de *templates* de acordo com critérios específicos.

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado Cigano. marcarei como resposta sua explicação pois eu entendi melhor sobre o assunto. Valeu !

Comment: @cigano_morrison_mendez cigano, fiz outra pergunta mais especifica, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149864/como-trocar-o-templatevisual-de-uma-pagina-asp-net-mvc5-de-acordo-com-usu%C3%A1rio