# Como trocar o template(visual) de uma pagina asp net mvc5 de acordo com usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, template

Galera é o seguinte, preciso ler uma propriedade que me retorne 1,2,3... e com ela eu determine qual o tipo de visual a pagina vai ter, template01,template02...

como eu faria isso usando areas, e navegando pelos controllers principal (que ficam na raiz do projeto).

basicamente é o seguinte: www.algumacoisa.com/home/index => redirecionar para o controller que vai verificar o valor que eu busquei no banco, e redirecionar para uma area pra retornar a view daquela area(template). minha maior duvida é como ficaria os retornos desses controllers.

E se alguém tiver uma ideia melhor sobre esse conceito sem usar areas, eu ficaria muito grato. Obrigado !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O segredo está na definição de um *ActionFilter*. Por exemplo:

```
public class LayoutChooserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{    
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string masterName = "_Layout";
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        string userName = null;
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        // Defina masterName aqui, de acordo com sua regra de negócio
        // por usuário. Você pode chamar o banco de dados aqui, se quiser.

        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = masterName;
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

Pode ser por *Controller*:

```
[LayoutChooser]
public class MeuController : Controller { ... }
```

Ou registro como filtro global (`Global.asax.cs`):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LayoutChooserAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ...
}
```

Comment: caraca velho, entao atraves disso eu posso fazer a minha regra pra definir o template e ainda fazer a consulta na propria sobrescrita.. valeu cigano ! vou estudar bem esse conceito.